# How to avoid "&" when creating file through batch file

Tags: batch-file, syntax-error

I have to redirect a vbs file through batch-file.

My code is like:

```
@echo off
echo Option Explicit>> weather.vbs
echo Dim LogFile,Ws,Tag,Content>> weather.vbs
echo LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, .)) & txt >> weather.vbs
echo Set Ws = CreateObject(wscript.Shell) >> weather.vbs
echo With CreateObject(InternetExplorer.Application) >> weather.vbs
echo     .Visible = False>> weather.vbs
echo    .Navigate http://aldweathersh2.blogspot.in/ >> weather.vbs
echo    Do Until .ReadyState = 4 >> weather.vbs
echo         Wscript.Sleep 6000>> weather.vbs
echo     Loop>> weather.vbs
echo     For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName(script) >> weather.vbs
echo         Tag.OuterHtml =  >> weather.vbs
echo     Next>> weather.vbs
echo     For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName(noscript) >> weather.vbs
echo         Tag.OuterHtml =  >> weather.vbs
echo     Next>> weather.vbs
echo     Content = .Document.GetElementsByTagName(body)(0).InnerText >> weather.vbs
echo     Do While InStr(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)>>weather.vbs
echo         Content = Replace(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf) >> weather.vbs
echo     Loop >> weather.vbs
echo     WriteLog Content,LogFile >> weather.vbs
echo    .Quit>> weather.vbs
echo End With>> weather.vbs
echo '******************************************************************* >> weather.vbs
echo Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile) >> weather.vbs
echo    Dim fso,ts>> weather.vbs
echo     Const ForWriting = 2 >> weather.vbs
echo    Set fso = CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject) >> weather.vbs
echo     Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile (LogFile,ForWriting,True,-1) >> weather.vbs
echo     ts.WriteLine strText>> weather.vbs
echo     ts.Close>> weather.vbs
echo End Sub>> weather.vbs
echo '******************************************************************>> weather.vbs
pause
```

Problem occurs with the batch-file while executing strings containing "&" in it.
Every time it breaks the redirection with "&".

Error is:

```
LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, .))
'txt' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
    Do While InStr(Content, vbCrLf
'vbCrLf)' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
        Content = Replace(Content, vbCrLf
'vbCrLf' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Is there any way to also redirect strings with "&" in batch-file ?

Comment: Can you escape the ampersand (&) by preceding it with a caret (^)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Escape the `&` (and other problematic characters) with `^`, so

```
echo     Do While InStr(Content, vbCrLf ^& vbCrLf)>>weather.vbs
```

Comment: You should also escape the `)` and perhaps the `(` because parentheses open/close blocks of code...

Comment: Not while in an `echo` statement.

Comment: As long as the `echo` is not within a block, escaping is optional; as soon as you have e. g. `(echo a(b)c)`, how should the parser know which `)` is the closing one? so you will definitely need `(echo a(b^)c)`; I prefer to escape also the opening one (although not mandatory) for the sake of readability, so I'd use `(echo a^(b^)c)`...

Answer (score 4):

Ouch.

GolezTrol provided a direct answer to your question - escape the `&` as `^&`.

But here is a useful tip, though it does not actually answer your question - When redirecting a group of commands to the same file, it is much more efficient (and easier to read) to redirect once.

```
(
  echo line 1
  echo line 2
  echo line 3
)>output.txt
```

However, the above would force you to escape any `)` as `^)` in your text.

Alternatively, you can redirect a CALL, and not have to worry about escaping `)`.

```
call :write >output.txt
exit /b
:write
echo line 1
echo line 2
echo line 3
exit /b
```

But really there is a much better way that eliminates the need to worry about escaping. Prefix each line with `:::`, and use FINDSTR to find lines, and FOR /F to remove the prefix. It is important that none of your desired text lines begin with `:`.

```
@echo off
:::Option Explicit
:::Dim LogFile,Ws,Tag,Content
:::LogFile = Left(Wscript.ScriptFullName,InstrRev(Wscript.ScriptFullName, .)) & txt 
:::Set Ws = CreateObject(wscript.Shell) 
:::With CreateObject(InternetExplorer.Application) 
:::    .Visible = False
:::   .Navigate http://aldweathersh2.blogspot.in/ 
:::   Do Until .ReadyState = 4 
:::        Wscript.Sleep 6000
:::    Loop
:::    For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName(script) 
:::        Tag.OuterHtml =  
:::    Next
:::    For Each Tag In .Document.GetElementsByTagName(noscript) 
:::        Tag.OuterHtml =  
:::    Next
:::    Content = .Document.GetElementsByTagName(body)(0).InnerText 
:::    Do While InStr(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf)
:::        Content = Replace(Content, vbCrLf & vbCrLf, vbCrLf) 
:::    Loop 
:::    WriteLog Content,LogFile 
:::   .Quit
:::End With
:::'******************************************************************* 
:::Sub WriteLog(strText,LogFile) 
:::   Dim fso,ts
:::    Const ForWriting = 2 
:::   Set fso = CreateObject(Scripting.FileSystemObject) 
:::    Set ts = fso.OpenTextFile (LogFile,ForWriting,True,-1) 
:::    ts.WriteLine strText
:::    ts.Close
:::End Sub
:::'******************************************************************
>weather.vbs (for /f "delims=: tokens=*" %%A in ('findstr "^:::" "%~f0"') do echo(%%A)
```

The `echo(` is an obscure syntax that is able to print lines that are empty or consist of nothing but spaces. It is more reliable than `echo.` It looks like it would mess up the parentheses blocks, but it doesn't. You don't have empty lines in your text, so it isn't an issue here, but it is a good trick to know.

The `::` acts as a comment, so those lines will not be executed.

There are two cases where the above technique can fail with a fatal syntax error:

- Your text contains `%~` that gets parsed as an invalid argument expansion.
- Your text contains `%var:=` where var is the name of an environment variable. The expression gets parsed as an invalid variable expansion find/replace operation.

If you run into either of the above problems, then you can simply put your text at the bottom of the script, with an EXIT /B before it.

If some of your lines begin with `:`, then you simply modify the prefix to end with a character that never begins a line, and change the FOR /F a bit. For example, suppose no line ever begins with `}`

```
::}Line 1
::}Line 2
::}Line 3
>output.txt (for /f "delims=} tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr "^::}" "%~f0"') do echo(%%B)
```

Another slight modification allows embedding multiple, independent blocks of text

```
::A}Line 1
::A}Line 2
::A}Line 3

::B}Line A
::B}Line B
::B}Line C

>a.txt (for /f "delims=} tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr "^::A}" "%~f0"') do echo(%%B)
>b.txt (for /f "delims=} tokens=1*" %%A in ('findstr "^::B}" "%~f0"') do echo(%%B)
```

Comment: Man, your answer makes me ashamed of mine. :/  :D